# Word not adjacent  to word in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

i have some bad words set like :

```
'aaa','bbb','ccc'
```

( bad words can be also , "john","paul","ringo") ( sorry @cyilan)

i dont want to allow `bad word` **immediately** followed by  another/same `bad word`

`aaa` can be followed by a non-bad word and `then` to be followed by a bad word :

```
  ...aaaRoyibbb...  //ok
  ...cccRoyiaaa...  //ok

   ...aaabbb...// NOT OK
   ...cccbbb...// NOT OK
   ...cccccc...// NOT OK
```

*a bad word is not allowed to be immediately followed with another/same bad word*

I've tried some regexps but with no success..

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: so near means *exactly adjacent* ?

Comment: Are there word boundaries around/before the words? Eg is `oooaaabbbkkk` `NOT OK` or `OK`?

Comment: By saying ``bad word``! you mean any word with all lower-cased. Am I right?

Comment: @Cylian it doesnt matter.... can i please call you on chat ?

Comment: @Qtax oooaaabbbkkk is not ok since aaa is a bad word folowed by bbb  (ooo is not a bad word and also kkk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "...aaabbb...";
if(!str.test(/(?:aaa|bbb|ccc){2}/)){
    // passed
}
```

Chat revealed that what OP really wanted was:

```
/^(?!(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)|.*(?:aaa|bbb|ccc){2}|.*(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)$)/
```

But really really:

```
^(?!(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b|.*\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\s+(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)\b|.*\b(?:aaa|bbb|cc‌​c)$)
```

Comment: If the words are separated, add a leading and ending word boundary anchor `\b`: `/\b(?:aaa|bbb|ccc){2}\b/`

Comment: how can i remove the NOT ?  ( it should be a part of a bigger regex) - so i need to check : `.......(?:aaa|bbb|ccc){0}.......` notice the {0}...

Comment: well it should also be mentioned that i didnt want to make it more complicated so i asked only about the middle part. In chat however i allowed myself to show him the whole picture, and indeed great solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
match = subject.match(/\b([a-z]{3})(?:(?!\1)|(?=\1))[a-z]+\b/i);
if (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: aaa,bbb is just a sample. it can be any bad word. not just `[a-z]{3}`. sorry cylian for not mentioned it. i thought it was cleatr.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for is \b. \b is defined as a word break. If it follows white space or numbers, it matches if the following text is letters. If it follows letters, it matches if the following is not letters (i.e. not a continuous word). It can be effectively used as an anchor tag, like this:

```
\byourword\b
```

It would match:

```
This is yourword, but not mine.
yourword is found in this sentence.
```

But it would not match:

```
When yourwordis found in other words, this will not match.
And ifyourword is at the end of another word, it will still not match.
```